# How to find out for each product, how many were sold in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
      Name Product  Amount
0      Bob   Apple       1
1      Bob  Banana       2
2  Jessica  Orange       3
3  Jessica  Banana       4
4  Jessica  Tomato       3
5     Mary  Banana       2
6     John   Apple       3
7     John   Grape       1
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('Bob','Apple',1), ('Bob','Banana',2), ('Jessica','Orange',3),
      ('Jessica','Banana',4),('Jessica','Tomato',3), ('Mary','Banana',2),
      ('John','Apple',3),('John','Grape',1)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Product','Amount'])
```

What I have done so far:

```
l = []
count=0
for i in range(0,8):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    
    if row.Product not in l:
        l.append(row.Product)
```

Now, `l` contains all the unique values in the Product column, but I need the total amount as well.

How can I find out for each product how many items were sold (for example, 4 units of Apple were sold)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `.groupby()` function:

```
print( df.groupby('Product')['Amount'].sum() )
```

Prints:

```
Product
Apple     4
Banana    8
Grape     1
Orange    3
Tomato    3
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

---

```
out = df.groupby('Product')['Amount'].sum()
print('{} units of Apple were sold.'.format(out.loc['Apple']))
```

Prints:

```
4 of Apple were sold.
```

Comment: You are the best! Thanks a lot.